# Trying to use gettimeofday to find elapsed time in milliseconds

Tags: c++, c

So I'm trying to use gettimeofday to find the elapsed time of an execution of code. But when I output it to stdout I get this very large number. The execution is only taking less than a second, but the output shows an elapse time of much longer.

```
struct timeval start, end;

gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

//code

gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
printf("Elapsed Time = %ld\n", (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + ((end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec)/1000000.0);
```

Code executes in less than a second but my output is -> 140734185085712

Comment: You can't just subtract `start.tv_usec` from `end.tv_usec`, any more than you can just subtract 9 from 3 when computing 43 - 19.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yes you can.  43 - 19 is `(4-1)*10 + (3-9)`  The -6 you get from 3-9 is just what you need to reduce the 30 from the first first bit to the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I commented too quickly, and I totally missed the real problem.  In my defense I will say that *if* the `tv_usec` field of `struct timeval` were unsigned, you might have a problem with the underflow.  (But typically it's signed, so never mind.)

Comment: If it's unsigned, you just have to cast it to signed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printf with %ld is expecting an integer instead of a float.  Try %f or similar instead of %ld.  Also, you might want to check for (and deal with) wraparound on the microseconds part.

Comment: This summer break really came and bit me in the ass, and clearly a chunk of my brain too. Thanks

Comment: Heh, no worries.  Happens to all of us.  The more you make these kinds of mistakes, the better you'll get at weeding them out.